# Inherited class is using methods from abstract parent in APScheduler job

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a problem that [APScheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) jobs are not running correctly. They are using methods from parent abstract class even having their own implementetion. It's not happening while launch function by command-trigger. All of this inside telegram API bot. Seems like this error appears only with `RedisJobStore`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import asyncio
import logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.redis import RedisJobStore


logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class MyAbstractClass(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def get_required_members(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    async def initiate_all(cls):
        members = cls.get_required_members()
        logging.info(f'Got {members=}')
        ...


class MyImplementation(MyAbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def get_required_members(cls):
        return ['Alex', 'Anna']

    @classmethod
    def append_to_scheduler(cls, scheduler: AsyncIOScheduler, run_date: datetime):
        return scheduler.add_job(
            func=cls.initiate_all,
            trigger='date',
            run_date=run_date
        )


redis_job_store = RedisJobStore()
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores={'default': redis_job_store}, logger=logging.getLogger())
scheduler.start()

run_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)
MyImplementation.append_to_scheduler(scheduler=scheduler, run_date=run_date)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Error:

```
Job "MyAbstractClass.initiate_all (trigger: date[2023-08-04 19:01:03 MSK], next run at: 2023-08-04 19:01:03 MSK)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/russich555/hdd/Programming/Freelance/YouDo/29.2pilot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base_py3.py", line 30, in run_coroutine_job
    retval = await job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/russich555/hdd/Programming/Freelance/YouDo/29.2pilot/mre/api.py", line 13, in initiate_all
    members = cls.get_required_members()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/russich555/hdd/Programming/Freelance/YouDo/29.2pilot/mre/api.py", line 9, in get_required_members
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

---

P.S. I posted this as [issue](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/767)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regression from [agronholm/apscheduler@5c69150](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/commit/5c69150815b37177a07204e6be74c8108e0891a6) (v3.1.0) (current version: v3.10.1).

It affects all job stores that use `job.__getstate__()`:

- `MongoDBJobStore`
- `RedisJobStore`
- `RethinkDBJobStore`
- `SQLAlchemyJobStore`
- `ZooKeeperJobStore`

You can patch `apscheduler.util.get_callable_name` to not use `func.__qualname__`:

```py
from apscheduler import util
from inspect import isclass


def get_callable_name(func):
    # `func.__qualname__` breaks inherited methods that call subclass methods
    # if hasattr(func, '__qualname__'):
    #     return func.__qualname__
    f_self = getattr(func, '__self__', None) or getattr(func, 'im_self', None)
    if f_self and hasattr(func, '__name__'):
        f_class = f_self if isclass(f_self) else f_self.__class__
    else:
        f_class = getattr(func, 'im_class', None)
    if f_class and hasattr(func, '__name__'):
        return '%s.%s' % (f_class.__name__, func.__name__)
    if hasattr(func, '__call__'):
        if hasattr(func, '__name__'):
            return func.__name__
        return func.__class__.__name__
    raise TypeError('Unable to determine a name for %r -- maybe it is not a callable?' % func)


util.get_callable_name = get_callable_name
```

Comment: Fixed in v3.10.2.